# Developing commercial solution on Opentaps

Tags: opentaps

Can a commercial solution be developed on Opentaps? 
If yes, what will be the consequence, if Opentaps converted to commercial license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for legal/licensing advice.

Comment: Hi, I would appreciate if you can guide me on where to post this question.

Comment: As on Opentaps site, I got this message: Important: the forum is closed. Please ask your questions on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=opentaps